# Divide a number by two different numbers in combination

Tags: divisibility

Similar to this question: [How to divide a number by $2$ numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/854503/336129)

I would like to know how to divide a number (let's say 23) by two different numbers (say, 1.6 and 2.4) to find what combination of the two different numbers makes up exactly 23 - or find out the remainder after reaching the closest number.

Unlike the linked question, I cannot guarantee that the number (23 here) is divisible by any combination of the two different numbers; on top of this I would like to find the most balanced combination of the two different numbers (such as 1.6*5 and 2.4*4 as opposed to 1.6*17 and 2.4*2, just pulling numbers out of thin air to explain the point here).

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I don't know where to start...

Comment: Well, the definition of divisibility and remainders go out of the window when you take rationals instead of integers.

Comment: Ah okay, well if you feel anything about my question ought to be changed feel free to make suggestions or use the built in "edit" functionality.

Comment: Alright. Here you have taken the number 23. Is that number supposed to be rational or integer? Similarly for the numbers that divide it. Are they rationals or irrationals?

Comment: All rational numbers, perhaps it would be better to work with money as the context here: £23 divided by combinations of £1.60 and £2.40. I'm afraid I won't be around for a few hours now, but thank you for any help you can offer.